# Force SAS to Continue in Proc Model after Singular Jacobian Error

Tags: sas, data-modeling

I have a data set with approximately 500,000 observations and for each observation I am attempting to solve a system of two non-linear equations. I do this as follows:

```
proc model data=myData;
eq.equationA= some non-linear equation in x and y;
eq.equationB=some different non-linear equation in x and y;
solve x y;
run;
quit;
```

From the log, the exact error I get is:
 The Newton method Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives of the equations with respect to the variables to be solved is singular at observation 1275, for iteration 2. The system of equations cannot be solved.

The problem here is that when this situation occurs SAS immediately terminates proc model. This is surprising in that normally SAS continues running when it encounters problems. How can I force SAS to simply skip the bad observation (1275) and continue running the model with subsequent observations? (I can't simply delete observation 1275 because I know other observations are likely to cause the same error going forward)

Comment: You have options NOERRORABEND, right?

Comment: @Kostya: The `noerrorabend` option would ensure that the SAS session doesn't terminate when it encounters an error. It doesn't affect whether a given procedure halts due to errors. That said, it certainly doesn't hurt to have it in your program.